# how to loop colors inside the "circle"?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, dom

I'm new to coding, how do I change colors to "bg-circle".

I want colors inside var "colors" to pass through the "circle". 
I've tried but I couldn't get the logic right.

Javascript

```
var colors = ["blue", "red", "blue"]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-circle">
    <div class="sm-circle"> 

    </div>          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
bg-circle{
width:40px;
height:40px;
border-radius:50%;
background:#ff7675;
}
```

Comment: Please replce 'bg-circle' with '.bg-circle' as a class selector in css, and help me understand the css for sm-circle, and on what basis you want to loop color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's what you are trying to achieve:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]
let currentColorIndex = 0;
//change color each second
setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

function changeColor() {
  document.querySelector('.bg-circle').style.backgroundColor = colors[currentColorIndex];
  currentColorIndex++;
  if(currentColorIndex == colors.length) {
    currentColorIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.bg-circle{
width:40px;
height:40px;
border-radius:50%;
background:#ff7675;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-circle">
    <div class="sm-circle">
    </div>          
</div>
```

If thats's the case here's a bit of an explanation:

Use `setInterval` method which executes a function every XXXX milliseconds where XXXX is set as a parameter. More about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp);

Loop through `colors` array by keeping the currently active index global and reset it when it exceeds the colors elements size. Thus you got a rotation of its elements.

When you got the correct color each second (in my case I set the interval to each second) you have to select the circle div. You can did it with `querySelector` which returns one element and directly set its background color property.

I've fixed an issue with the css class styling. You miss the dot in front of the classname in your css code.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var colors = ["blue", "red", "blue"];
let i = 0;
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("bg-circle")[0];
setInterval((color) => {
  x.style.background = colors[i];
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.bg-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff7675;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-circle">
  <div class="sm-circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JavaScript.

```
var colors = ["blue", "red", "blue"];
for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('bg-circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simple do this using `setInterval` and loop throw these colors.

```js
var colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]

var smCircule = document.querySelector(".bg-circle");
var index=0;
setInterval(()=> {
smCircule.style.background = colors[index];
index++;
if (index>=colors.length)
    index=0;

},1000)
```

```css
.bg-circle{
width:40px;
height:40px;
border-radius:50%;
background:#ff7675;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-circle">
    <div class="sm-circle"> 
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm here to tell you : "you can do that in CSS".

```css
.bg-circle{
    animation-name:toRed;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:25px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

@keyframes toRed{
    from{
      background-color:blue;
    }
    to{
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-circle"></div>
```

If that's a smooth change between colors you want. You can also use multiple colors by changing the "from to" structure of the keyframes to 0%, 35%; 75%, 100%. Have a great day.